# Unresolved external or linker error

Tags: linker, unresolved-external

I have posted my 2 source files.  I've been trying to find out whats wrong for the last 6 hours but I cannot find the solution to these errors:

1>Mainirk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall pokemon::pokemon(int,int,int)" (??0pokemon@@QAE@HHH@Z) referenced in function "void _*cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'enemy''(void)" (??*_Eenemy@@YAXXZ)

1>C:\Users\Taylor\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\irkling\Debug\irkling.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Mainirk.cpp and stats.h

//mainirk.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include "include/irrKlang.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include "stats.h"



#pragma comment(lib, "irrKlang.lib")
using namespace std;
using namespace irrklang;





int choose();
void charmander1();
void bulbasaur1();
void squirtle1();
void yourpokemon();
void enemypokemon();
void battle();
void bchoice();
void aichoice();



int axisx;
int axisy;
void grid();
void events();


void attack();
void defend();
int x;
int y;
int z;
int m;
int n;
void win();
void lose();
void results();
void talk1();
void travel();
int walk;
void refresh();
void enemy1();



int achoice;

pokemon enemy(1,2,1);
pokemon charmander(25,3,25);
pokemon bulbasaur(20,4,20);
pokemon squirtle(30,2,30);


int main()
{


choose();
yourpokemon();
cout<<"\nPress any key to continue.";
_getch();
system("cls");
cout<<"********************************";

cout<<"\nEverything suddenly goes dark.\n";
cout<<"\n\nYou feel a dark presense enter the area.\n";
cout<<"Your rival Chuy walks in and challenges you to a battle...\n\n\n";
cout<<"................==\n";
cout<<".............../´¯/)\n\n";
cout<<"............/....//\n\n";
cout<<".........../....//\n\n";
cout<<"...../´¯/..../´¯<\n\n";
cout<<".././.../..../..../.|\n\n";
cout<<"(.(....(....(..../.)..)\n\n";
cout<<".<......(...(.....</.../\n\n";
cout<<"..<.................<\n\n";
cout<<"....<..............<\n\n";
cout<<"......<.............<\n\n";
cout<<"\n________________________________\n";
cout<<"Press any key to continue..\n\n";
ISoundEngine* se = createIrrKlangDevice();
se->play2D("Red.mp3");
_getch(); 

system("cls");
do
{
battle();
aichoice();
_getch();
system("cls");
}
while (y>0 && m>0);
cout<<"Battle Over\n";
results();
refresh();
_getch();
system("cls");
talk1();
_getch();
do
{
grid();
travel();
events();
system("cls");
}
while (axisx!=100);
return 0;
}




int choose()
{

cout<<"Choose your pokemon!!!\n\n";
cout<<"********************************\n\n";
cout<<" Charmander has "<<charmander.hp()<<" hp and "<<charmander.dmg()<<"          damage.\n\n";

cout<<" Bulbasaur has "<<bulbasaur.hp()<<" hp and "<<bulbasaur.dmg()<<" damage.\n\n";

cout<<" Squirtle has "<<squirtle.hp()<<" hp and "<<squirtle.dmg()<<" damage.\n\n";
cout<<"--------------------------------\n\n";

cout<<"Type [a] to choose Charmander\n\n";

cout<<"Type [b] to choose Bulbasaur\n\n";

cout<<"Type [c] to choose Squirtle\n\n";
char answer;
cin>>answer;




 if (answer == 'a'||answer == 'A')
 {
 answer = 'a';
 }

 if (answer == 'b'||answer == 'B')
 {
 answer = 'b';
 }

 if (answer == 'c'||answer == 'C')
 {
 answer = 'c';
 } 




 switch (answer)
 {

if (answer =='a')
{
    case 'a': charmander1();
    enemy = squirtle;
    y= charmander.hp();
    z= charmander.dmg();
    x= charmander.bhp();

}
 if (answer == 'b')
 {
case 'b': bulbasaur1();
    enemy = charmander;
y = bulbasaur.hp();
z = bulbasaur.dmg();
x= bulbasaur.bhp();

 }
if (answer == 'c')
 {
case 'c': squirtle1();

enemy = bulbasaur;
y = squirtle.hp();
z = squirtle.dmg();
x= squirtle.bhp();

 }

 }return 0;
 }

 void charmander1()
 {
 cout<<"You have chosen the Pokemon Charmander!!!\n";
 cout<<"Charmander is a fire type!\n";
 }

 void bulbasaur1()
 {
 cout<<"You have chosen the Pokemon Bulbasaur!!!\n";
 cout<<"Bulbasaur is a grass type!\n";
 }

 void squirtle1()
 {
 cout<<"You have chosen the Pokemon Squirtle!!!\n";
 cout<<"Squirtle is a water type!\n";
 }

 void yourpokemon()
 {

 cout<<"HP is "<<y<<" and damage is "<<z;
 }



 void battle()
 {
 cout<<"\n\tStatus\t\t";
 cout<<"\n-----------------------\n";
 cout<<"Your Pokemon\tEnemy Pokemon\n";
 cout<<"HP: "<<y<<"\t\tHP: "<<m<<"\n";



 bchoice();
 }

 void bchoice()
 {
 cout<<"\n\nType 1 to attack or 2 to defend\n";

 cin>>achoice;

 if (achoice ==1)
 {
 attack();
 }
 else if (achoice ==2)
 {
 defend();
 }
 else 
 {
 cout<<"Retype your choice"<<endl;

 }
 }

 void attack()
 {
 m = m-z;
 cout<<"\nYour Pokemon attacks!";
 }

 void defend()
 {
 cout<<"\nYour pokemon defends!";
 }



 void aichoice()
 {
 if (achoice ==1)
 {
 cout<<"\nThe enemy pokemon attacks!";
 cout<<"\nPress any key to continue";
 y = (y-n);
 }


 else if (achoice ==2)
 {
 cout<<"\nThe enemy pokemon defends!";
 cout<<"\nPress any key to continue";
 }
 }


 void win()
 {
 cout<<"You have won the battle!\n";
 }

 void lose()
 {
 cout<<"You have lose the battle!\n";
 }

 void results()
 {
 if (y>0 && m <= 0)
 {
     win();
 }
 else if (m>0 && y <= 0)
 {
     lose();
 }


 }

 void talk1()
 {
 cout<<"These animals are merely pawns in a series that is about to unfold\n";
 cout<<"If i were you, I would enjoy my last days alive\n";
 cout<<"*Chuy walks away..*\n";
 }

 void travel()
 {

 cout<<"\nIt is time to travel\n";
 cout<<"Type 1 to travel North\n";
 cout<<"Type 2 to travel South\n";
 cout<<"Type 3 to travel West\n";
 cout<<"Type 4 to travel East\n";
 cin>>walk;
 if (walk ==1)
 {
     axisy++;
 }
 if (walk ==2)
 {
     axisy--;
 }
 if (walk ==3)
 {
     axisx--;
 }
 if (walk ==4)
 {
     axisx++;
 }

 }

 void grid()
 {
 cout<< "location Coordinates: "<<axisx<<","<<axisy<<"\n";

 }

 void events()
 {
 if (axisx ==5 && axisy ==10)
 {
     battle();
 }

 }

 void refresh()
 {
 m = enemy.bhp();

 }

 void enemy1()
 {
 m = enemy.hp();
 n = enemy.dmg();
 }




//stats.h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class pokemon
{
int health, damage, basehp;

public: 

pokemon (int,int,int);
int hp() 
{
return (health);
}

int dmg()
{
return (damage);
}
int bhp()
{
return (basehp);
}

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you *declared* a constructor `pokemon` that takes 3 integer parameters, but did not provide its *implementation*. You could either provide it inline in the header

```
class pokemon
{
    int health, damage, basehp;
public: 
    pokemon (int _health, int _damage, int _basehp)
    :  health(_health)
    ,  damage(_damage)
    ,  basehp(_basehp) {
    }
    // ...
};
```

or separately in the cpp file, like this:

```
pokemon::pokemon(int health, int damage, int basehp) {
    // do your initialization here...
}
```

Comment: I must be putting it in wrong. I keep getting the same error.  How exactly would it look in my header?

Comment: @Chuy I edited the answer to include an example of how to define your constructor in the header.

Comment: i changed it to this now.  How do i make it so the main.cpp can output squirtle.hp(); ? says canot recognize hp.  The old error isnt there anymore so i know im closer to making this work =). #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class pokemon
    {
      int health, damage, basehp;
      public: 
      pokemon (int hp, int dmg, int bhp)
 :  health(hp)
       ,  damage(dmg)
       ,  basehp(bhp) {
   
  }
     // ... 
    };

Comment: Not sure how to make changes to the code to make it neat, it says im not allowed to edit yet.

Comment: @Chuy You shouldn't call your variable `hp`, it's the name of one of your methods. You can copy-paste from my answer, I deliberately added `_` to avoid name collisions. Also, you should be able to edit your own post - I think there's a link for that. I'm not sure about editing comments, though.

Comment: thank you! Your are a life saver! I put some more thought into it and changed it.  This is the best site i ever came across. Thanks for your patience.